# java.lang.StackOverflowError causing problems in my app

Tags: java, android, loops, stack-overflow

I am having a problem with my app, I cannot figure out what the problem is.  On ICS the app works, but on anything 2.X it has problems.  I believe it has to do with the loop but I am still a bit confused.

Developer console throws this at me for the error report:

```
Exception class > java.lang.StackOverflowError
Source method > Matrix.setScale()
```

This is the code that is causing the problem...

```
private void shiftLoop7()
{
    if (d7 != doy && d7 < 366)
    {
        d7 = d7 + 8;
        shiftLoop7();
    }
    else if(d7 == doy)
    {

        if (hour >= 0 && hour < 8)
        {
            shift.setText("C");
            shift.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.CShift);

            shiftImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
            timeTill.setText("till 7:45 AM");

            dayshift.setText("A Shift");
            day1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);

            nightshift.setText("C Shift");
            night1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
        }
        else if (hour >= 8 && hour < 17)
        {
            shift.setText("A");
            shift.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AShift);

            shiftImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
            timeTill.setText("till 4:45 PM");

            dayshift.setText("A Shift");
            day1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);

            nightshift.setText("C Shift");
            night1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
        }
        else
        {
            shift.setText("C");
            shift.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.CShift);

            shiftImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
            timeTill.setText("till 7:45 AM");

            dayshift.setText("A Shift");
            day1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);
            day4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.A);

            nightshift.setText("C Shift");
            night1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
            night4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.C);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        shiftLoop8();
    }
}
```

Comment: TLDR; You need to strip it back to the minimum required for us to see the problem. Should be fairly easy since you are actually getting an exception rather than a hang or a crash etc.

Comment: TOO MUCH CODE - and you don't seem to have a reference to setScale anywhere in there.

Comment: i don't use setScale anywhere, which is why i was wondering what that was refering to.  but all is good now, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @SkateJerrySkate - if you had included the stacktrace we might have been able to answer that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common cause of stack overflow is a large number of recursive calls - either due to a bug causing infinite recursion, or code that is just structured to have very deep recursion.

In your case, the stack overflow may be caused by the fact that your code has potential for a fairly large depth of recursive calls.  Could you restructure the recursive calls to just be while loops?  For example, instead of:

```
if (d7 != doy && d7 < 366)
{
    d7 = d7 + 8;
    shiftLoop7();
}
```

could you just do the following:

```
while (d7 != doy && d7 < 366)
{
    d7 = d7 + 8;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to give, your call depth could be 366 calls by the end, which is simply too much for a mobile device.

Comment: Thanks a lot Happy Dave, that seems to have fixed my problem.  I love StackFlow.